# Adjusting fixed header and click functions

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, css-position

I have a fixed div with anchors that when clicked "jump" to an area on the page. Due to the body being beneath the fixed div when the page jumps my destination is overlapped by the fixed header.

The element that is being jumped to uses a data attribute to toggle between tabs. I've tried to dynamically add padding to the body when the jump click event fires, but there was a timing issue. To overcome that I added `setTimeout` so the padding is added in sequence to work.

The click event resets when a second click event takes place which should keep the tabs div where it is beneath the fixed div, but that isn't the case. I have to essentially remove the padding style when clicked and add it back at timed interval using the same `setTimeout` function. This works, except the transition is abrupt.

Next I added a `fadeOut` function with a null value and then `fadeIn` with a positive value of `1`. This quickly hides the element and fades it back in, but the timing is too late to eliminate the abrupt padding transition and besides, the elements below the tabs are also affected by the padding values.

**How can I force the page / elements to position beneath the fixed div on scroll so it isn't overlapping to solve the problem at hand?**

---

```
jQuery(".totab").click(function() {
    jQuery("body").css({
            "padding-top" : ""
            });
    function delayHashedClick(){
        jQuery("body").css({
            "padding-top" : "110px"
        });
        jQuery(".hashed").fadeOut();
        jQuery(".hashed").fadeIn(1);
    }
    setTimeout(delayHashedClick, 150);
});
```

https://sites.btwebnetwork.com/btwebgroup (click events in second nav drop-down menu)

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` with an `onload` event that applies the desired CSS when an anchor#hash is opened, then using the `click` function to do the rest of the magic maintains a consistent experience however you end up at the content. There is still some abrupt jumping, but most visitors will utilize the tabbed navigation and not the anchor#hash nav at that point.

It isn't perfect and the timeout and fade transition times had to be played with a little to get it looking OK.

```
function delayHashedLoad(){
    jQuery(".hashed").css({
        "margin-top" : "140px"
    });
    }
window.onload = setTimeout(delayHashedLoad, 1200);
//
jQuery(".totab").click(function() { 

    function delayHashedReset(){
        jQuery(".hashed").css({
            "margin-top" : ""
        });
    jQuery(".hashed").fadeOut();
    }
    delayHashedReset();

    function delayHashedClick(){
        jQuery(".hashed").css({
            "margin-top" : "130px"
        });
        jQuery(".hashed").fadeIn(500);
    }
    setTimeout(delayHashedClick, 1000);
});
```